# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage with AppsFlyerFramework pod

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cocoapods, app-store-connect, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I am making an update to a legacy iOS app but App Store Connect isn't accepting the our new build. I get the message:

*ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.*

Since our app isn't using UIWebView I figured out that some of the pods that we use might need an update. I finally figured out what pod causes the problem. Now I just don't know why. Or how to fix it.

I have disabled all Firebase code and AppsFlyer code in our app. I just include the pods into the build and send them to Apple to test if the build is accepted. I need to have FirebaseCore in the podfile because AppsFlyer linking fails without it.

My very minimal podfile now looks like this:

```
target 'app' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'

end
```

This is rejected by Apple. But *if I remove the AppsFlyerFramework from the podfile the build is accepted.*

Does the latest AppsFlyerFramework contain some referenced to UIWebView still? What could cause this issue?

Comment: Remove `Podfile.lock` and do `pod install`, then you will get the latest version of `AppsFlyerFramework `

Comment: It is already v. 6.12.2 (the latest)